# NHibernate query strategies in web applications

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate

In web application scenarios, there are commonly two requirements regarding data retrieval:
1. All queries need to be paged optionally
2. There are alot of "filtering" queries needed by the user (e.g. search Person by name AND mail AND age)
3. Sorting queries implied by some clientside grid

And of course the combined case: Filtered, paged queries which are sorted :)

These requirements can lead to alot of repository methods in the data layer, each with alot of parameters. 
Are there any common patterns of giving this process a more dynamic behavior (e.g. auto-generated queries depending on domain class properties)?

I'm aware of the fact that repository methods should be clean and well-defined. But at the moment, I feel like writing alot of boilerplate code whenever I add some filtering form to an MVC-view or some sortable paged table.

How do other developers handle such requirements?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Repositories, [generic repositories](http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2009/01/16/ddd-the-generic-repository/) and repositories that expose IQueryable is a much heated debate.

**The bottom line is a repository that is generic or exposes IQueryable is not a a real repository at all, it is merely an abstraction of your data layer.**

Now this is not a bad thing to have but don't call it a repository, call it what it is. A data layer abstraction allows you to quickly insert something into your UI where you read and write entities without leaking your data layer framework into the UI. You could of course just inject an `ISession` and be done with it.

```
public interface IRepository<T> {}

public class NHibernateRepository<T> : IRepository<T>
{
    private ISession session;

    public NHibernateRepository(ISession session)
    {
        this.session = session;
    }

    T Get(object id) { return session.GetById<T>(id)); }

    IQueryable<T> Query { get { return session.Query<T>(); }
}

new NHibernateRepository<Customer>(session).Query().Where(customer => customer.Name == Fred);
```

However if you want to capture some reusable logic and provide a clear contract between your services or UI and your data layer then a [Repository](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx) does just that. You define clear methods that says what it is retrieving and how. Additionally with a repository you only want to expose your [aggregate roots](http://domaindrivendesign.org/node/88), these are the root entities to which all your other data hangs off, these could be things like `Customer` and `Supplier`. You wouldn't try to get to an address directly you would load up a customer and then query his addresses. You would load a list of suppliers based on what things they supply but you wouldn't go via a 'ItemsRepository'. My examples may not be the best but they give you an idea.

```
public class CustomerRepository
{
    public Customer GetCustomerWithName(string name);
}

public class SupplierRepository
{
    public IEnumerable<Supplier> GetSuppliersWhoStockItem(string itemName)
}
```

Finally if your adventurous you might want to look at [CQRS](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html), it is to big of a subject to outline here but there are plenty of examples.

The first is quicker to implement, the second gives you clearer reusable code, the third gives you a separation between your UI layer but requires more ground work. It depends on what you need and want and should probably be tackled in that order.

Comment: Thank you Bronumski, I think I'll take a combined aproach: well-defined methods called by web services and additional IQueryable-interface to handle generic queries from the web frontend.

Answer (score 3):

In our project we've used repositories too, repository per entity, but I don't enjoy about it.
It can do a lot of problem when you write complex queries with a lot of interact entities.
I think it'll be a one generic repository for base operations, and all queries should be present with Query Object pattern, something like separate class per query, although look at:

http://richarddingwall.name/2010/06/15/brownfield-cqrs-part-1-commands/

http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2009/01/20/ddd-specification-or-query-object/

http://devlicio.us/blogs/casey/archive/2009/02/13/ddd-command-query-separation-as-an-architectural-concept.aspx

http://blog.jonathanoliver.com/2009/10/dddd-why-i-love-cqrs/

http://www.udidahan.com/2007/03/28/query-objects-vs-methods-on-a-repository/

Answer (score 3):

You use a Repository to enumerate an aggregate root. Often enough, your controllers work with an aggregate root, which you may filter, sort, etc. as the user requires.

Therefore, I use a repository along the lines of what has already been mentioned.

However, sometimes I need to work within more complex specifications, where using an aggregate root and/or a whole bunch of repositories is either painful, inefficient, or just not possible. For example, you may need to run a large business report, or perhaps execute a batch command.

In these sorts of cases, I have also defined `ICommand`/`IQuery`, with an NH base implementation to take care of the plumbing stuff (like a generic `Repository` does).

What I then do is make an interface that represents the contract for the specification, exposing any members I may need to help me build the required parameters. Then I make an implementation of that specification, using NH as the backbone, fulfilling the specification using whatever technique is most suitable (an HQL statement, raw SQL, Criteria, QueryOver... whatever).

Here is a crude illustration of what I mean. Note that I use an arbitrary `ICommandProvider`, which is some object that creates new instances of a command as needed (in case you need to issue several commands in one operation). I would register my commands with an IoC and have the provider work with it to create the command instances.

```
public interface ICommand
{

}

public interface ICommandProvider
{
    TCommand Create<TCommand>()
        where TCommand : ICommand;

}

public interface IQuery<TResult> : ICommand
{
    TResult Execute();
}

public class NhCommand : ICommand
{
    // plumbing stuff here, like finding the current session
}

public class DelinquentAccountViewModel
{
    public string AccountName { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}

public interface IDelinquentAccountsQuery : IQuery<IEnumerable<DelinquentAccountViewModel>>
{
    void AmountGreaterThan(decimal amount);
    // you could define members for specifying sorting, etc. here
}

public class DelinquentAccountsQuery : NhCommand
{
    public IEnumerable<DelinquentAccountViewModel> Execute()
    {
        // build HQL and execute results, resulting in a list of DelinquentAccountViewModels
        // using _amountGreaterThan as a parameter
        return null;
    }

    private Decimal _amountGreaterThan;

    public void AmountGreaterThan(Decimal amount)
    {
        _amountGreaterThan = amount;
    }
}
```

Usage in a controller might be something like this:

```
public class DelinquentAccountsController : Controller
{
     protected ICommandProvider CommandProvider { get; private set; }

     public DelinquentAccountsController(ICommandProvider commandProvider)
     {
         CommandProvider = commandProvider;
     }

     public ActionResult Index(decimal amount)
     {
         var query = CommandProvider.Create<IDelinquentAccountsQuery>();
         query.AmountGreaterThan(amount);
         return View(query.Execute());

     }
}
```

Nothing says you can't do all of your data access using a command/query, but it's more work than I need. I find that the standard repository approach (using LINQ against NHibernate) handles 95% or so of the data access my applications require.

Answer (score 1):

You could make your Repository provide an IQueryable and let the ActionMethod figure out what to display. For instance:

```
    public System.Linq.IQueryable<Models.MyModel> Query()
    {
        return mSession.Query<Models.MyModel>();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Imho orm is enough abstraction already. You don't need repositories on top of that. You only need abstraction if you're going to change orm on the fly with some setting. Where, Skip, Take, OrderBy etc. are orm agnostic and can be used by exposing IQueryable. But some features are orm specific (like fetch vs. include) and those make repositories really ugly (million methods or method with million parameters)

I usually just make extension methods

```
public static class QueryExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> Published(this IQueryable<T> pages) where T : IPage
    {
        return pages.Where(p => p.State == PageState.Public && p.Published <= DateTime.UtcNow);
    }
    public static IQueryable<T> By(this IQueryable<T> pages, User author) where T : IPage
    {
        return pages.Where(p => p.Author == author);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Foo> AdvancedThing(this ISession session, string text)
    {
        // I get all the power of NHibernate :)
        return session.CreateQuery("...").SetString("text", text).List<Foo>();
    }
}
```

and use ISession directly in action methods

```
var posts = session.Query<Post>().By(user).Published().FetchMany(p => p.Tags).ToList();
```